# php radio button value calculation

Tags: php, html

I'm beginning php and stuck/ confused by this seemingly simple process.
I have a radio button list with different values that I want to calculate in a simple equation.

I want to add the value with a number that is determined by the number of selected checkboxes then output this as a price. eg. if radio 1 is selected its value is $140, there are also 4 boxes ticked each worth $10, how can I output the value total of $180? 
here is my html code for the radio

```
<input type="radio" name="math" id="standard" value="140">
<label for="youth">mid range value</label>
<input type="radio" name="math" id="extra" value="180">
<label for="youth">extra cost</label>
```

and some of the checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="more[]" id="a"
value="10"> <label for="val1">box a</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="more[]"id="b"
value="10"> <label for="val">box b</label><br>
```

how can I add the values which is dependant on the number of selected checkboxes?

any help, or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Well as I'm sure you know the `math` value is acquired from `$_REQUEST['math']` (after the form is submitted).  This would be `140` (or `180`, etc.)

`$_REQUEST['more']` will be an array with values corresponding to each selected value.  You can actually get the sum fairly easily with `array_sum($_REQUEST['more'])`, which will yield the sum of each selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get this using JavaScript on each radio checked event you have to add the value of the control and on unchecked the control you have to minus the value so you get your answer.